# Android AndEngine - How can I update ChangeableText value

Tags: android, text, andengine

I have a little problem with ChangeableText in AndEngine. I want to know how to update it's text without freezing the screen? For now I'm using this way, but it's freezing my phone for maybe 2-3 seconds :

```
    private void removeFace(final Sprite face) {

        hm = getIconNames();
        if(face.getUserData().equals("petrol")){

            elapsedText.setText(hm.get(25));           

            final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face);

            this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
            this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());
            this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(face);
            this.mScene.detachChild(face);

        } else {

        }

        System.gc();
}
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when you detachChild you should do this in thread because if you don't it can causes errors. Use this construction

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(yourSprite.hasParent())
                    scene.detachChild(yourSprite);
            }});
```

You can put there all code if you want then your phone shouldn't freez

```
    private void removeFace(final Sprite face) {
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                hm = getIconNames();
                if(face.getUserData().equals("petrol")){

                    elapsedText.setText(hm.get(25));           

                    final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face);

                    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
                    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());
                    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(face);
                    this.mScene.detachChild(face);

                } else {

                }

                System.gc();
                }});


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because you are fetching some information while setting the text.

What you should do is, get your

```
String hm = hm.get(25); //What ever the correct object is or variable. im guessing its a string or int.
```

Then

pass it to the Changeable text to be set.

```
elapsedText.setText(hm);   //If its a int make sure you do String.valueOf(hm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only 3 methods here that have the possibility to take long are `getIconNames()` and `get()`, and `System.gc()`

The others are usually methods that return immediately, or have a very low complexity. For example, `getPhysicsConnectorManager()` returns immediately. `findPhysicsConnectorByShape`, `unregisterPhysicsConnector`, `unregisterTouchArea` and `detachChild` all have complexity of O(n), (And most of the others methods also have complexity of O(1) or O(n)).

I recommend you to look in the LogCat and when `System.gc()` is called, you will see a `Log.i` (blue) message of the tag of `dalvikvm` which will begin with `GC_EXPLICIT` and will give you some information about how long did the garbage collection took, etc....

If that GC call isn't taking the time, it must be your 2 methods, `getIconNames()` and `hm.get()`. You can put a Log.d message after each code line, which will write the last code line executed. This way you can follow the times.